# no Internet connection warning message on Windows 10, but internet is working

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a clean install of Windows 10 home edition, 64 bit.

Everything seems to be working fine but in the panel on the bottom right I have a yellow triangle in the network connection box which when I click onto it says no internet connection even though I do.

I have reinstalled the adapter several times, made sure everything is enabled.  I use an Ethernet connection to a router, getting really connection speeds to internet and within the network, but its just annoying.

Comment: Provide us the output on "ping Google.com" and a screenshot of your network diagram

Comment: I would not worry about it... but i am curious to the fix as i have about 30 Windows 8.1 Enterprise machines that are doing the same.

Comment: ............... <sigh>